# How to store API data (array) into database with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having error trying to store data into a database. I need help on how best to fix this my code, so that my array content can be stored in a my database. When I tried to echo the content, it worked not to store the data in my database is the problem.
Here is my code:

```
foreach ($data['players'] as $myp) {
//    echo $myp["name"]."<br>";
    $name = $myp['name'];
    $posi = $myp['position'];
    $nation = $myp['nationality'];
    $market = $myp['marketValue'];
}

//insert into mysql table
mysql_select_db($db, $conn); //database and connection 

$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s'); //date stamp formatting
//sql query that insert the user info into the database
$sql =  "INSERT INTO staffdb ( Name, Position, Nationality, Market, Created)       
        VALUES($name, $posi, $nation, $market, $date)";
echo $name . "<br>";
//if the connection is sucessful, display regards message
if (mysql_query($sql, $conn)) {
    echo "Thank you <br/>";
} else {   //if the connection is not established
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Here is the error I was getting:
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '**Costa, Centre Forward, Spain, 45,000,000 €, 2017-03-31 23:03:04**)' at line 2

In the error it printed the right value which i would like to be instead stored in the database.

Kindly correct my SQL part so that I can get my **foreach** data into my database.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need quotes around your values, plus you might want to use mysqli (as far as i know mysql_query etc. is deprecated.
Also with your code only the last player is inserted.. don't know if that's what you want?

in your foreach you could do something like $q .= "('$name', '$posi', '$nation', '$market', '$date'),";

And then after the foreach loop removing the last comma $q = rtrim($q, ",");

And then the sql query:  $sql = "INSERT INTO staffdb ( `Name`, `Position`, `Nationality`, `Market`, `Created`)VALUES".$q;

EDIT: something like this:

```
$values = "";
$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
foreach ($data['players'] as $myp) {
//    echo $myp["name"]."<br>";
    $name = $myp['name'];
    $posi = $myp['position'];
    $nation = $myp['nationality'];
    $market = $myp['marketValue'];

    $values .= "('$name', '$posi', '$nation', '$market', '$date'),";
}
//remove last comma
$values = substr($values, 0,-1);

//mysqli connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

//sql query that insert the user info into the database
$sql =  "INSERT INTO staffdb ( Name, Position, Nationality, Market, Created)       
        VALUES".$values;
//if the connection is sucessful, display regards message
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
echo "Thank you <br/>";
```

Comment: You are very correct, the sql only insert the last object into the db. That not what I want, I want all to be inserted. Any idea thanks?

Comment: @Addey i gave my ideas already but i've updated my post with basically a copy paste answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your values. In addition you should use PDO and bind those values.

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO staffdb ( Name, Position, Nationality, Market, Created)       
        VALUES('$name', '$posi', '$nation', '$market', '$date')";
```

Comment: Thanks solved...

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around your field names:

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO staffdb ( Name, Position, Nationality, Market, Created)       
    VALUES('$name', '$posi', '$nation', '$market', '$date')";
```

You should read up on SQL injection as your code is very vulnerable.

Also, you should move the closing `}` tag from your foreach loop so it comes at the end of your code. That way each item in your array will be added to your database.

Comment: Thanks solved...

Comment: Hi, thanks. I moved the closing } as you said but only the first 4 elements that are add. Kan you help me on how to get every element stored? Also after i moved the mysqli_select_db to either above or below the foreach, it gave error: Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Golo Kanté', 'Defensive Midfield', 'France', '30,000,000 €', '2017-04-0' at line 2. Am pretty new in php, kan you help me thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap values in query into quotes:

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO staffdb ( `Name`, `Position`, `Nationality`, `Market`, `Created`)
      VALUES('$name', '$posi', '$nation', '$market', '$date')";
```

---

Very recommend, how it's possible, move into new `mysqli` or `PDO` extension.

Comment: Thanks solved...